# Two Charges on sides of an Uncharged Metallic Cube How to Find Electric Field Inside the Metallic Cube?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, textbook-erratum

[image: Situation that shows charges are brought near Metallic Cube. Question is to Find Resultant Electric Field at points A and B.]

The Electric Field must be zero inside the Metallic cube but as per the text book answer there is electric field at Point P which is closer to the left side of the Metallic cube. There is a possibility that Diagram is incorrect i.e. the Point P is outside the conductor.

The second point was on Distribution of Induced Charges on this Cube. My understanding is that both the sides of cubes facing the Charged will have equal negative charge but then where would positive charge appear for electrostatic Equilibrium.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

---

My understanding is that in both situations Hollow Metallic Cube and Solid Metallic Cube the Induced charges will appear on the Surface and there cannot be any NET electric field inside the Metallic Cube i.e Electric Field is 0 at both P and Q. But as per the text book answer the Electric Field exists at Point P. Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What textbook? (Author, title, edition)

Comment: Modern abc+ Physics for Class 12 (Set of 2 Volume) (2019-2020) Examination Paperback – 1 January 2019 
by Uttam Narayan Tripathi (Author)